# How to set programmatically topBar and bottomBar parameters of UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

In the interface builder there are few parameters for UIView of UIViewController:
topBar, bottomBar, ...

[image]
interface builder parameters of view

What happens when i set Navigation Bar value for Top Bar parameter,
and Tab bar for Bottom Bar parameter? It is very useful to me.

So, how can i do it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Actually this parameters are using for building correct interface and even if you will set this bars in Xcode Interface Builder, they will not appear, if you are not using you UIViewController inside some UIViewController containers.

As example if you will add your UIVIewController into UINavigationController, then you will see Navigation Bar as top Bar.
This Simulated metrics have no effect in the program, but they will help you to build correct interface, if you expect to use UIViewController inside container.

But if you want to add this Parts of interface programmatically inside your UIViewController, you can use according subiews.
As example:

```
UINavigationBar *yourBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:yourBar];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that bars will not appear, but this parameters affect to layouting view controllers view and its subViews. I mean, i can't set self.view.frame = CGRect(x, y, width, height) in viewDidLoad method, it will haven't any affect to view position. What can I do programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you cannot, and why do you need this? 
Main view  of UIViewController will allways take whole place of your main view.

Or you can add your UIViewController inside required container if you need:
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourController];

Then you will have nav bar as in the Simulated Metric. And your UIVIewController will have sizes like when using simulated metrics

Comment: I have a viewController in navigationController in TabBarController, in this viewController i have a UIView, its name containerView, in the controller i add views from other viewControllers to the containerView as subviews one by one, and layout of views of viewControllers with seted bottomBar and topBar options is good, but   views of viewControllers without xibs (and this options) layouted incorrect. The autoresized masks is correct, difference between those controllers only in that parameters (bottomBar and topBar)

Comment: If you are adding views from other viewControllers, you can use frame for them.
UIViewController *contoller;
[containerView addSubview:controller.view];
[controller.view setFrame:yourFrame];

In your interfaceBuilder set Status Bar, Top Bar, Bottom Bar to None. And then you can resize your UIVivew in interface builder to yourFrame

Comment: Yes, i already did it :) not work, and incorrect offset of position of subViews of added view is equals to navbar and tabBar sizes. )

Comment: The question was "So, how can i do it programmatically?", i mean without interface builder. And if i set that parameters to none in other controllers, they also will be incorrect layouted. Thanks